# Create chat message layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with my chat message `Layout` in Android.

I have 3 custom `textview`, but the Time of `textView` should be set on `Bottom` and `Right align`.

Here is my screenshot:

[image]

And here is my code:

```py
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/msg_in"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.fearefull.chatstory.Widgets.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/nickname_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="none"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="adawd awdaw"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,RtlHardcoded" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.fearefull.chatstory.Widgets.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="none"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="dlsadfafawfafawawfawf a fawfawfafafkawmflaknfalfntigtggt"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,RtlHardcoded" />

        <com.fearefull.chatstory.Widgets.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="11:15 PM"
            android:textColor="#a6abad"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textview_message"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I used any Alignment for my Time of `textView`, but it didn't work.

Comment: please check my answer.

Comment: check my answer or you can add one line in "textview_message" textview with "android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textview_time""

Comment: @Saif This way I get a lot of empty space in right of my text message.

Comment: @ArefHosseini then also set this android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" in your textview_message

Comment: @Saif If we have some sentences, the time and message get Horizontal orientation and we lose lots of upper space of time message.

Comment: @ArefHosseini okay then you can add your time in last of your message means remove your time textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout should be like this. You should get ride of the RelativeLayout and simply change your view's layout gravity

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/msg_in"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.fearefull.chatstory.Widgets.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/nickname_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="none"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="adawd awdaw"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,RtlHardcoded" />


        <com.fearefull.chatstory.Widgets.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="none"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="dlsadfafawfafawawfawf a fawfawfafafkawmflaknfalfntigtggt"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,RtlHardcoded" />

        <com.fearefull.chatstory.Widgets.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="11:15 PM"
            android:textColor="#a6abad"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="5dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is modify your layout from **RelativeLayout** to LinearLayout and you are good to go.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
android:background="@drawable/msg_in"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.fearefull.chatstory.Widgets.MyTextView
    android:id="@+id/nickname_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="none"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:paddingBottom="7dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="12dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:text="adawd awdaw"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,RtlHardcoded" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.fearefull.chatstory.Widgets.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="none"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="dlsadfafawfafawawfawf a fawfawfafafkawmflaknfalfntigtggt"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,RtlHardcoded" />

    <com.fearefull.chatstory.Widgets.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="11:15 PM"
        android:textColor="#a6abad"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:padding="5dp"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.fearefull.chatstory.Widgets.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/nickname_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="none"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="adawd awdaw"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,RtlHardcoded" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.fearefull.chatstory.Widgets.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="none"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="dlsadfafawfafawawfawf a fawfawfafafkawmflaknfalfntigtggt"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,RtlHardcoded" />

        <com.fearefull.chatstory.Widgets.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="11:15 PM"
            android:layout_below="@id/textview_message"
            android:textColor="#a6abad"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="2dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: @Aref Hosseini Welcome Happy to help you.

Comment: I miss something, this way the chat message get match parent width and there is no different that message has one word or full of sentence like this.
we have different length of message and get match parent with for all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/msg_in"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.fearefull.chatstory.Widgets.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/nickname_message"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="none"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:paddingBottom="7dp"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:text="adawd awdaw"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,RtlHardcoded" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.fearefull.chatstory.Widgets.MyTextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="none"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:paddingRight="12dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textview_time"
                android:text="dlsadfafawfafawawfawf a fawfawfafafkawmflaknfalfntigtggt"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                tools:ignore="ObsoleteLayoutParam,RtlHardcoded" />

            <com.fearefull.chatstory.Widgets.MyTextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="11:15 PM"
                android:textColor="#a6abad"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/textview_message"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```